# Open Android Database in Delphi 2007

Tags: android, delphi

Just completed an Android App version of my PC Software......Now to Step 2, designed a utility that will import the Android Database to the PC Versions Database, Looking for the best method of doing so....Since I believe Android ships with SQLite version 3.4.0, what would be the best delphi components to use for Delphi 2007 Open Source and free would be good but not required.

One more thing.......I'm using Absolute Database by http://www.componentace.com for my PC Versions Database

Thanks

Comment: If the Android database is in the Android device, how (over which communication method) does the Delphi application connect to it? Or will the database file be copied from the Android device to the PC first?

Comment: I plan to have it copied from the Android device to the PC first?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to access the SQLite database directly from Delphi: if your app can communicate with a web server and post its data using HTTP, then on Delphi side you can use Indy or Synapse open source TCP libraries to retrieve the data from this server, aagain using HTTP with a message body in a standard format like JSON or XML.
The Delphi app then can parse the data using a library like Synapse or NativeXml and insert it in the Absolute Database tables.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: No it does not but thanks......I need to keep this simple so I plan to have it copied from the Android device to the PC first?